# want to get data from specific column of azure mobile service table using linq

Tags: c#, linq, azure-mobile-services, windows

**I have taken a textbox,a textblock and a button to perform a search kind of thing in azure mobile service table...I give username of person in textbox and when i click the button i want to get firstname in the textblock whose username is given in the textbox..m new to this so dont know how to do...please help me..ihave tried the following code but its not working**

```
private async void search_click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
 {
        MobileServiceCollection<UserData, UserData> data;
        IMobileServiceTable<UserData> dataTable = App.MobileService.GetTable<UserData>();

        try
        {
            showBlock.Text = "searching.....";
            statusBar.IsIndeterminate = true;
            searchButton.IsEnabled = false;
            if (searchBox.Text != "")
            {
                tempUnamePhone = await App.MobileService.GetTable<UserData>().Where(x => x.uname == searchBox.Text || x.phone == searchBox.Text).ToListAsync();
               data = await dataTable.Where(x => x.uname == searchBox.Text).Select(x=>x.fname).ToCollectionAsync();


            }
            if (tempUnamePhone.Count != 0)
            {
                showBlock.Text = "item found"+fname;
                statusBar.IsIndeterminate = false;
                searchButton.IsEnabled = true;
            }
            else
            {

                showBlock.Text = "no match found";

                statusBar.IsIndeterminate = false;
                searchButton.IsEnabled = true;
            }
        }
        catch (Exception )
        {
            var m = new MessageDialog("Network error..close the app and try again" ).ShowAsync();
        }

    }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var fname = string.Empty;
if (searchBox.Text != "")
        {
            tempUnamePhone = await App.MobileService.GetTable<UserData>().Where(x => x.uname == searchBox.Text || x.phone == searchBox.Text).ToListAsync();
            fname =tempUnamePhone.Where(x => x.uname == searchBox.Text).FirstOrDefault() == null ? string.Empty : await dataTable.Where(x => x.uname == searchBox.Text).First().fname;
```

**Here the matched records will get as a collection. I don't see the code to find fname from the collection.I believe fname is intended to store first name from the matched record. 
You have to check whether any records returned in 'data'and then assign the first record to 'fname', 
then set to the textblock**

```
         if (tempUnamePhone.Count != 0)
        {
            showBlock.Text = "item found" + fname;      
            statusBar.IsIndeterminate = false;
            searchButton.IsEnabled = true;
        }
        else
        {

            showBlock.Text = "no match found";

            statusBar.IsIndeterminate = false;
            searchButton.IsEnabled = true;
        }
```

Comment: IT SHOWING THESE TWO ERRORS: 1 The name 'fname' does not exist in the current context 
 2:'Microsoft.WindowsAzure.MobileServices.IMobileServiceTableQuery<searchbox.UserData>' does not contain a definition for 'First' and no extension method 'First' accepting a first argument of type 'Microsoft.WindowsAzure.MobileServices.IMobileServiceTableQuery<searchbox.UserData>' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Comment: add System.Linq to namespace(using System.Linq;). and declare fname.

Comment: Then try FirstOrDefault(). "First()" is actually working fine for me